# How to solve for variable inside of Re[ ] function?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve for x in the following equation

```
NSolve[ c == Re[ Sqrt[ (((a - b I) x^2) / ((a - b I) - x^2)) ] ] , x ]
```

It seems to be too much for NSolve.

Comment: Your code gives a syntax error.

Comment: Does a closed form solution even exist for that input?

Comment: I have corrected it. Thats why I tried to used NSolve, but that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqn = c == Re[Sqrt[(((a - b I) x^2)/((a - b I) - x^2))]];

sol = Assuming[Element[{a, b, c, x}, Reals],
   Solve[eqn && Element[{a, b, c, x}, Reals],
     x] // Simplify];
```

The solutions are [`ConditionalExpressions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) involving [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. For example,

```
sol[[-1]]

(* {x -> ConditionalExpression[√Root[
     4 a^4 c^4 + 8 a^2 b^2 c^4 + 
       4 b^4 c^4 + (-4 a^4 c^2 - 8 a^2 b^2 c^2 - 4 b^4 c^2 - 16 a^3 c^4 - 
          16 a b^2 c^4) #1 + (12 a^3 c^2 + 12 a b^2 c^2 + 24 a^2 c^4 + 
          8 b^2 c^4) #1^2 + (-12 a^2 c^2 - 4 b^2 c^2 - 
          16 a c^4) #1^3 + (-b^2 + 4 a c^2 + 4 c^4) #1^4 &, 2], 
   b != 0 && (0 < c < 
       Root[-b^2 + 4 a #1^2 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] || (a > -(Abs[b]/Sqrt[3]) && 
        Root[-b^2 + 4 a #1^2 + 4 #1^4 &, 2] < c < 
         Root[-27 a^4 - 54 a^2 b^2 - 27 b^4 + 64 b^2 #1^4 &, 2]))]} *)
```

Using specific values for `a`, `b`, and `c`, the exact values are

```
sol2 = sol /. {a -> 3/10, b -> 7/10, c -> 1/10}
```

[image]

`Undefined` indicates that the conditions for the `ConditionalExpression` are not met. The numeric values for the solutions given as `Root` objects are

```
sol2[[-2 ;;]] // N

(* {{x -> -0.0997478}, {x -> 0.0997478}} *)
```

Verifying the solution with the exact values

```
eqn /. {a -> 3/10, b -> 7/10, c -> 1/10} /. sol2[[-2 ;;]] // RootReduce

(* {True, True} *)
```

or with approximate real numbers

```
eqn /. {a -> 3/10, b -> 7/10, c -> 1/10} /. N[sol2[[-2 ;;]]]

(* {True, True} *)
```

Alternatively, assigning values to `a`, `b`, and `c` prior to solving provides identical solutions

```
sol2[[-2 ;;]] === 
 Solve[{eqn /. {a -> 3/10, b -> 7/10, c -> 1/10}, Element[x, Reals]}, x]

(* True *)
```

Using [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) requires that `a`, `b`, and `c` be assigned values prior to solving

```
NSolve[{eqn /. {a -> 3/10, b -> 7/10, c -> 1/10}, Element[x, Reals]}, x]

(* {{x -> -0.0997478}, {x -> 0.0997478}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd transform the equation into

$$
c+i d = \sqrt{\frac{(a-ib)x^2}{(a-ib)-x^2}}
$$

where $d$ is a real-valued variable to be determined along with $x$.
Then square both sides to get rid of the square root,

$$
(c+i d)^2 = \frac{(a-ib)x^2}{(a-ib)-x^2}
$$

Assuming that $a$, $b$, $x$ are all real-valued, the right-hand side has real and imaginary parts

```
RHS = ((a - b I) x^2)/((a - b I) - x^2) // ReIm // ComplexExpand
```

> {(a^2 x^2)/(b^2 + (a - x^2)^2) + (b^2 x^2)/(b^2 + (a - x^2)^2) - (a x^4)/(b^2 + (a - x^2)^2), (b x^4)/(b^2 + (a - x^2)^2)}

For the left-hand side, the real and imaginary parts are

```
LHS = (c + I d)^2 // ReIm // ComplexExpand
```

> {c^2 - d^2, 2 c d}

Set both sides equal and find $x$ and $d$, then only look at the result for $x$:

```
S[a_, b_, c_] = x /. Solve[Thread[LHS == RHS], {x, d}]
```

Test: for $a=0.3$, $b=0.7$, $c=0.1$ we get two real-valued solutions for $x$:

```
Select[S[0.3, 0.7, 0.1], Im[#] == 0 &]
```

> {-0.0997478, 0.0997478}

Because we squared the equation, we need to make sure these solutions actually work out:

```
Re[Sqrt[((a - b I) x^2)/((a - b I) - x^2)]] /.
  {a -> 0.3, b -> 0.7, x -> 0.09974779931802105`}
```

> 0.1

works!